# Could not import "google.golang.org/appengine/delay"

Tags: go, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-app-engine-golang

I am trying to create a Google analytics tracking beacon by following [this git repo](https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon) have gotten stuck trying to solve why this one import keeps throwing errors.

The specific issue comes from this import:
`"google.golang.org/appengine/delay"`

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/appengine/delay"
)

const beaconURL = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect"

var (
    pixel        = mustReadFile("static/pixel.gif")
    badge        = mustReadFile("static/badge.svg")
    badgeGif     = mustReadFile("static/badge.gif")
    badgeFlat    = mustReadFile("static/badge-flat.svg")
    badgeFlatGif = mustReadFile("static/badge-flat.gif")
    pageTemplate = template.Must(template.New("page").ParseFiles("page.html"))
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", port)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func mustReadFile(path string) []byte {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return b
}

func generateUUID(cid *string) error {
    b := make([]byte, 16)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    b[8] = (b[8] | 0x80) & 0xBF // what's the purpose ?
    b[6] = (b[6] | 0x40) & 0x4F // what's the purpose ?
    *cid = hex.EncodeToString(b)
    return nil
}

var delayHit = delay.Func("collect", logHit)

func sendToGA(c context.Context, ua string, ip string, cid string, values url.Values) error {
    client := &http.Client{}

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", beaconURL, strings.NewReader(values.Encode()))
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", ua)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    if resp, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
        log.Printf("GA collector POST error: %s", err.Error())
        return err
    } else {
        log.Printf("GA collector status: %v, cid: %v, ip: %s", resp.Status, cid, ip)
        log.Printf("Reported payload: %v", values)
    }
    return nil
}

func logHit(c context.Context, params []string, query url.Values, ua string, ip string, cid string) error {
    // 1) Initialize default values from path structure
    // 2) Allow query param override to report arbitrary values to GA
    //
    // GA Protocol reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

    payload := url.Values{
        "v":   {"1"},        // protocol version = 1
        "t":   {"pageview"}, // hit type
        "tid": {params[0]},  // tracking / property ID
        "cid": {cid},        // unique client ID (server generated UUID)
        "dp":  {params[1]},  // page path
        "uip": {ip},         // IP address of the user
    }

    for key, val := range query {
        payload[key] = val
    }

    return sendToGA(c, ua, ip, cid, payload)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := r.Context()
    params := strings.SplitN(strings.Trim(r.URL.Path, "/"), "/", 2)
    query, _ := url.ParseQuery(r.URL.RawQuery)
    refOrg := r.Header.Get("Referer")

    // / -> redirect
    if len(params[0]) == 0 {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon", http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    // activate referrer path if ?useReferer is used and if referer exists
    if _, ok := query["useReferer"]; ok {
        if len(refOrg) != 0 {
            referer := strings.Replace(strings.Replace(refOrg, "http://", "", 1), "https://", "", 1)
            if len(referer) != 0 {
                // if the useReferer is present and the referer information exists
                //  the path is ignored and the beacon referer information is used instead.
                params = strings.SplitN(strings.Trim(r.URL.Path, "/")+"/"+referer, "/", 2)
            }
        }
    }
    // /account -> account template
    if len(params) == 1 {
        templateParams := struct {
            Account string
            Referer string
        }{
            Account: params[0],
            Referer: refOrg,
        }
        if err := pageTemplate.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", templateParams); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "could not show account page", 500)
            log.Printf("Cannot execute template: %v", err)
        }
        return
    }

    // /account/page -> GIF + log pageview to GA collector
    var cid string
    if cookie, err := r.Cookie("cid"); err != nil {
        if err := generateUUID(&cid); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to generate client UUID: %v", err)
        } else {
            log.Printf("Generated new client UUID: %v", cid)
            http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{Name: "cid", Value: cid, Path: fmt.Sprint("/", params[0])})
        }
    } else {
        cid = cookie.Value
        log.Printf("Existing CID found: %v", cid)
    }

    if len(cid) != 0 {
        var cacheUntil = time.Now().Format(http.TimeFormat)
        w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private")
        w.Header().Set("Expires", cacheUntil)
        w.Header().Set("CID", cid)

        logHit(c, params, query, r.Header.Get("User-Agent"), r.RemoteAddr, cid)
        // delayHit.Call(c, params, r.Header.Get("User-Agent"), cid)
    }

    // Write out GIF pixel or badge, based on presence of "pixel" param.
    if _, ok := query["pixel"]; ok {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/gif")
        w.Write(pixel)
    } else if _, ok := query["gif"]; ok {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/gif")
        w.Write(badgeGif)
    } else if _, ok := query["flat"]; ok {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")
        w.Write(badgeFlat)
    } else if _, ok := query["flat-gif"]; ok {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/gif")
        w.Write(badgeFlatGif)
    } else {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")
        w.Write(badge)
    }
}
```

Upon finding the [golang appengine git repo](https://github.com/golang/appengine), it advises to run the following command:
`go get google.golang.org/appengine/cmd/aefix`

Unfortunately, doing this in both Powershell and Cloud Tools for Powershell with local admin rights, I get this error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> go get google.golang.org/appengine/cmd/aefix
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
        To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
        like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
        For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
        or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
```

How can this be solved so I can not get any error with `google.golang.org/appengine/delay` as an import?

Comment: The error is `go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory`. How have you setup your module?

Comment: I just cloned the repo to my Windows Desktop and tried deploying it straightaway.  Is there an initial step I missed?  I'm coming from a Node.js background where we typically run `yarn` or `npm i` to install everything but this is my first experience with `go`.  Please let me know if there's possibly a step I forgot to take initially.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to use modules to manage dependencies. Please start with the basic docs, like [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code) or the [Getting Started](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started) tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried running `go install google.golang.org/appengine/cmd/aefix`?